# Why does linking a gpu freeze QEMU in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, virt-manager

I am running a Ubuntu on a workstation with 2 GTX 1070 and I5 7400 CPU, I have QEMU installed and I have an old windows 10 vm I tried to link the GPU by adding the PCI link hardware in virt-manager GUI, and restored windows vm (from a saved state) it detects a PCI hardware but does not install any drivers, I powered the VM completely then tried to run it again but I got this error

```
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: host doesn't support passthrough of host PCI devices
```

so I check if VT is enable and it is, since
`sudo rdmsr 0x3A` returns a `5`

next step I did was to check `kvm-ok` and I got

```
 INFO: /dev/kvm exists
 KVM acceleration can be used
```

everything seems okay so far so I used

`virt-host-validate` and realized `IOMMU` is not enabled so I did the following, edited
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=on"` followed by `update-grub`

now `IOMMU` is enabled since `virt-host-validate` outputs

```
  QEMU: Checking if IOMMU is enabled by kernel                               : PASS
```

now when I try to run the same vm without the pci link it works fine but adding the pci link causes the `libvirtd` to timeout and freeze

```
авг 28 00:45:22 WORKSTATION systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1814 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
авг 28 00:45:22 WORKSTATION systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 1815 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
авг 28 00:45:22 WORKSTATION systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 4018 (libvirtd) remains running after unit stopped.
авг 28 00:45:22 WORKSTATION systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
```

The output pf `dmesg`

```
[32729.791574] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000500] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[32729.792216] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000900] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

am I missing something, do I need to enable any extra features or maybe disable any?

Comment: Have you excluded the other GPU from your Linux driver? The Linux GPU driver must not manage the GPU you want to pass-through. Please add `dmesg` output right after boot so we can see the status.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen please check the updated question

Comment: This is only part of `dmesg` output, please add the full output after system boot.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen please check the output in the pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/yU53b3v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `dmesg` output it is visible that the Linux kernel loads drivers for both cards.

In order to free the device for your VM, you need to unbind the driver from it. [https://www.iram.fr/~blanchet/ethercat/unbind_manually_pci_device.html](https://www.iram.fr/%7Eblanchet/ethercat/unbind_manually_pci_device.html) tells how to unbind the driver from a device.

First, find PCI slots and actual drivers:

```
lspci -Dk
```

The output might look like:

```
0000:01:06.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 8255xER/82551IT Fast
```

Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Kernel driver in use: e100
0000:01:07.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 8255xER/82551IT Fast
Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Kernel driver in use: e100

You need to find the NVidia entries there. You might need to guess which device is the one you are using.

You need to note the PCI ID (`0000:01:07.0`) and driver name (`e100`) for your GPU.

Then you can issue

```
echo -n "<pci id>" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/<driver>/unbind
```

You need to replace `<pci_id>` and `<driver>` with the values you got from `lspci` output. This will unbind the NVidia driver from the specified device, freeing it up for PCI passthrough.

Comment: so I only have to unbind the gpu and i am good to go?

Comment: That is the most likely blocker here. I cannot definitely say it is the only reason.

Comment: So i used the command `echo "<pci id> | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/unbind"` but this never returns to the terminal and the only option is to reboot the system even using `kill <pid>` does not help I already asked a question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715246/how-to-unbind-a-gpu-sys-bus-pci?noredirect=1#comment1355276_715246) but thought i would mention it here